# Using splice to extract nested array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use `splice` to extract a nested array. What I get instead is an array of the required size with `undefined` on each element

```js
  var testCurrProds = [ 'Prod1', 'prduct1', 'Prod1'] 
  var testCurrProds1 = [ 'Prod2', 'prduct2', 'Prod2', 'Prod2', "Prod9"] 
  var testCurrProds2 = [ 'Prod3', 'prduct3', 'Prod3', 'Prod3', "Prod9"] 
  var testCurrProds3 = [ 'Prod4', 'prduct4', 'Prod4', 'Prod4', "Prod9", "Prod9", "Prod98"]   


  var testString = [1, 'tName1', 4, 69, 'Haircare', "T1", "false", "false", testCurrProds]
  var testString1 = [2, 'tName2', 1, 69, 'Skincare', "T1", "false", "true", testCurrProds1]
  var testString2 = [3, 'tName3', 3, 69, 'Haircare', "T1", "true", "true", testCurrProds2]
  var testString3 = [4, 'tName4', 5, 69, 'Skincare', "T1", "true", "false", testCurrProds3]
  var testPackages = [testString, testString1, testString2, testString3];

  var currPackage = popArray(testPackages, 1, 'tName1');
  console.log(currPackage);
  
  function popArray(x, findID, findName)
  {
      //return array containing submitted ID 
      for (var k = 0; k < x.length; k++ )
      {
          //console.log(x[k]);  
          if((x[k][0]==findID) & (x[k][1]==findName))
          {
              //var temp = x.splice(k,1)
              //console.log(temp);
              return x.splice(k,1);
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Don't change the array you're iterating over.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: it does not matter with an immediate return statement.

Comment: I can't reproduce this — adding `return temp` and it seems to work. Can you post a runnable snippet that shows the behavior?

Comment: The aim is to find the array of I want from the nested array, mutate it as I please, and then return it to the tail if I so choose (may just delete)

Comment: Can you post the data contained in the array?

Comment: Please give us sample input, and expected output.  Furthermore, is `&` really what you intend, or rather `&&`

Comment: Are you calling `splice` twice? It looks like the return has another splice commented out.

Comment: so I updated the code to when the exact scenario when the error occurred, I had commented out and all of that to debug and try find the cause

Comment: Just a simple typo... `tname1 !== tName1`

Comment: typo was coz of rushing to type here

Comment: If so, than this is not a [mcve] because it still works: https://jsbin.com/jaduluvama/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

An array comprehension can be used here, which I think is easier to understand and less error-prone than the iterative method.

```
function popArray(arrayOfArrays, findID, findName) {
    const index = arrayOfArrays.findIndex(a => a[0] == findID && a[1] == findName);
    return index !== -1 && arrayOfArrays.splice(index, 1)[0];
}
```

Basically, this just uses the built-in findIndex function to locate the match, and then splices it out of the array and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the code I have not found any issue with the logic and code except you are using the single '&' sign for 'and' logical condition.

```
function popArray(x, findID, findName)
{
  //return array containing submitted ID 
  for (var k = 0; k < x.length; k++ )
   {
    //console.log(x[k]);  
    if((x[k][0]==findID) && (x[k][1]==findName))
    {
        var temp = x.splice(k,1)
        console.log(temp);
        //return x.splice(k,1);
    }
  }
}
```

see this attached image. I ran this code and got the expected output.
http://prntscr.com/m0baai